# How Can I replace javascript url with array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have written a code in jquery to replace the URL link and array.

```
<form action='' method="post" id="bulkDeleteForm">
        <button class='button-secondary-warning' id="bulkDelete" style="margin-left: 73%; margin-top: 2%"><span class='fas fa-times'></span>Bulk Delete</button>
    </form>
```

```
        $("#bulkDeleteForm").submit(function (event) {
            var assignments = [1,2,3,4,5]; //example array
            var clinicalAssignments = ["4","7","8","9"]; //example array

            var url = '@Url.Action("BulkDelete", "Assignments", new { schoolId = school.Id, courseId = Model.Course.Id, assignments = "-1", bulkClinicalAssignments = "-2" })';
            url = url.replace("-1", assignments);
            url = url.replace("-2", clinicalAssignments);
           
            $("#bulkDeleteForm").attr('action', url);
        });
```

Now when the form has submitted the value of assignments and bulkClinicalAssignments is not replaced with the array it is rather comma separated value. How can I replace that parameter with the array?

Comment: Better to create the url part vise and add the array values into it. May solve your problem

Comment: Better to just make an `$.ajax({method:"POST", data: { assignments, clinicalAssignments }, url: '@Url.Action...'` (Url.Action without the -1/-2 placeholders) and let jquery POST for you - you don't want those parameters on the URL for a POST anyway, they should be in the post's `body`.  Don't forget to `return false` from the `.submit` and handle reloading of the page.

Comment: Alternatively, use `<input type='hidden'>` in your `form`, set the values in those and post/submit the form normally.   Messing about with the URL like that for a POST is just asking for issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo to replace javascript url with array:

js(array in url looks like `array=xxx&array=xxx&array=xxx`,and you need to use `@Html.Raw()` so that there will have `&` rather than `&amp;` in the url):

```
$("#bulkDeleteForm").submit(function (event) {
            var assignments = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; //example array
            var clinicalAssignments = ["4", "7", "8", "9"]; //example array
            var url = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("BulkDelete", "Assignments", new { schoolId = 1, courseId = 2, assignments = "-1", bulkClinicalAssignments = "-2" }))";
            var assignmentsUrl = "";
            assignments.forEach((element) => { assignmentsUrl += "assignments=" + element + "&" });
            url = url.replace("assignments=-1&", assignmentsUrl);
            var clinicalAssignmentsUrl = "";
            clinicalAssignments.forEach((element) => { clinicalAssignmentsUrl += "bulkClinicalAssignments=" + element + "&" });
            url = url.replace("bulkClinicalAssignments=-2", clinicalAssignmentsUrl.substring(0, clinicalAssignmentsUrl.length - 5));
            $("#bulkDeleteForm").attr('action', url);
    });
```

Model:

```
public class ArrayModel
    {
        public int schoolId { get; set; }
        public int courseId { get; set; }
        public List<int> assignments { get; set; }
        public List<int> bulkClinicalAssignments { get; set; }

    }
```

action:

```
public IActionResult BulkDelete(ArrayModel a)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

result:
[image]